# jQuery load() is not loading content properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history, html5-history

I am trying to load new links without page refresh using html5 `window.history.pushState()` function.

Everything works good but when I open my inspect element in Chrome or in Firefox the `head` tag and `body` tag are missing. I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
function goto(event,el)
{
    url=el.href;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState('','',url);
    $('html').load(url);
}
```

and the new loading page is this:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<a href="menu1.php">Menu1</a>
<a href="menu2.php">Menu2</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really want to navigate through pages without page refresh properly.

How to solve this issue using `history.pushstate()` function or is there any other way.

My main motive is to achieve speed like Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193958/discussion-on-question-by-donm-jquery-load-is-not-loading-content-properly).

Answer (score 0):

Load your page by AJAX like this and use `replaceWith`:

```
$.get( url, function( data ) {
    //data is the new page html
    document.open(); 
    document.write(data); 
    document.close();
});
```

***UPDATE***

I highly recommend using this library from Github instead:

[smoothState](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js)

Comment: @donm I tried it and it worked, would you please update your question and provide your complete HTML and javascript code?

Comment: I tried your code and check the console and it's show an error :-

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document-fragment' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document

Comment: I use this code and everything work perfectly like the way i want

Here is the code:-

 $.get(url, function(data) {
  //data is the new page html
  document.open();
  document.write(data);
  document.close();
 });

Comment: @alireza-yazdaandost please check the above code is this okay it may cause any problem in future or with any conflict with js or css

Comment: @donm my answer works if you get an HTML file as `url`, but when you get it from the server your answer is exactly correct, so I edited my answer for possible future references :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193963/discussion-between-alireza-yazdandoost-and-donm).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many options but I found my solution on this code

```
function goto(event,el)
{
    url=el.href;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState('','',url);
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var head=data.match(/<head[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\/head>/gi);
        $('head').html(head[0]);
        $('#content').html($(data).find('#content').html());
    }); 
}
```

Do you have any better solution than this and is this solution works same in all the browsers and what about speed/load time/performance issue is there any.

My main purpose to load new page content without page refresh instantly like twitter or facebook doing

Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated